# Issue in tomcat 7.0 to configure tomcat to support ssl

Tags: tomcat, ssl

To support ssl in tomcat....I make a Keystore file. that contain self-signed certificate.....and then open server.xml file of tomcat 7.0 and locate this code in server.xml

```
`     <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->

     <!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /> -->    `
```

and remove comment from connector and  put **KeystoreFile** entry and **KeystorePass** entry in uncommented connector code like following this.........

```
`    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
      maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
      clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" **keystoreFile**="d:\cpademo.keystore"
     **keystorePass**="cpademo"/>      `

The above code works in tomcat 6.0...and allow https connection with tomcat but i get the error in tomcat 7.0 log file which indicate that it does not suppoert connection to https 8443 connection. Error in log file is following as.....

ERROR:

SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-ap
r-8443"]
java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when
using SSL with APR
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:484)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:554)
```

Pls help me sort out this problem. Thanx in advance

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 17):

You are using the APR/native connector with the SSL configuration for the JSSE connectors (BIO and NIO). The simplest fix will be to comment out the APR lifecycle listener in server.xml.

Comment: You may also need to use `keyPass` instead (or in addition to) `keystorePass` in Apache Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 11):

You must change `protocol` from

```
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
```

to

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

Here's a good article
http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

mkyong's article is outdated and lacks the change I proposed above.